# How to delete all records(rows) before specific date in powershell?

Tags: powershell, rows

I'm trying to write a code that would delete all rows before specific date (date is stored in column 1) based on the text string stored in column 8.My text file is really big (more than 800 000 rows) so I'm not sure if my code is the best way to do it. So far my code is just deleting all rows before $date1.

```
$date1 = Read-Host 'Enter date1 mm/dd/yyyy'
$date2 = Read-Host 'Enter date2 mm/dd/yyyy'
$header="Date,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,Header8" | Out-File test.txt -encoding "Default"
get-content .\bigfile.txt |select -Skip 1 | where { [datetime]($_.split(','))[0] -ge $date1} | Out-File test.txt -encoding "Default" -append
```

So for text strings in column 8 where last 3 characters are "-XX" or ".YY" all rows before $date1 should be deleted. And for text strings in column 8 where last 3 characters are other than "-XX" or ".YY" , all rows before $date2 should be deleted.
I really hope that my description is clear enough. I'm sorry if its not.

Please see test file below:
bigfile.txt

```
Date,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,Header8
8/14/2014,11.4,11.4,11.07,11.11,52930,0,Text1
8/15/2014,11.18,11.18,10.78,10.81,80517,0,Text1
8/18/2014,10.92,11.12,10.81,11,188671,0,Text1
8/14/2014,11.09,11.79,11.036,11.49,142205,0,Text2-XX
8/15/2014,11.43,11.738,11.32,11.7,70846,0,Text2-XX
8/16/2014,11.67,12.56,11.458,12.42,170739,0,Text2-XX
8/17/2014,12.47,12.79,12.22,12.66,176367,0,Text2-XX
8/14/2014,12.7,13.5,12.6,13.26,411410,0,Text3
8/15/2014,13.35,13.62,13.17,13.55,209561,0,Text3
8/16/2014,13.55,13.57,13.28,13.49,104880,0,Text3
8/14/2014,13.4,13.61,13.14,13.18,167355,0,Text4.YY
8/15/2014,13.17,13.17,12.67,13.04,119659,0,Text4.YY
8/16/2014,13.07,13.07,12.64,12.73,133181,0,Text4.YY
8/15/2014,12.75,13.43,12.75,13.38,154302,0,Text5
8/16/2014,13.43,13.78,13.28,13.49,203535,0,Text5
8/17/2014,13.43,14.29,13.38,14.24,167803,0,Text5
8/18/2014,14.26,14.53,13.79,13.91,124665,0,Text5
8/19/2014,13.87,13.95,13.25,13.3,123747,0,Text5
8/20/2014,13.27,13.45,12.79,12.94,128408,0,Text5
8/21/2014,12.81,13.22,12.81,13.1,74911,0,Text5
8/15/2014,13.09,13.26,12.81,13.01,204025,0,Text5.YY
8/16/2014,13.07,13.07,12.58,12.64,75625,0,Text5.YY
8/17/2014,12.52,13.26,12.52,13.26,115968,0,Text5.YY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might perform better where you have 1000's of rows of data. The only stipulation is that you should remove the first row of data from the file manually since this method reads the rows in chunks and having an if statement for every row to check for a header seems like a waste

```powershell
$output = C:\temp\test.txt

$date1 = Read-Host 'Enter date1 mm/dd/yyyy'
$date2 = Read-Host 'Enter date2 mm/dd/yyyy'

Set-Content -Path $output -Value "Date,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,Header8"

Get-Content C:\temp\data.log -ReadCount 500 | ForEach-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
    $line = $_
    $splitLine = $line -split ","
    $singleDate = [datetime]$splitLine[0]
    $queryColumn = $splitLine[7]

    If (($queryColumn -match "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and $singleDate -ge $date1) -or ($queryColumn -notmatch "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and $singleDate -ge $date2)){
        $line
    }
} | Add-Content $output
```

I swear I didn't steal Mads logic.

**Account for the header**

I couldn't come up with a clever way to deal with the header expect by using a `if` statement. This *shouldn't* add too much to the processing time.

```powershell
Get-Content C:\temp\data.log -ReadCount 500 | ForEach-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -notmatch "header"){
        $line = $_
        $splitLine = $line -split ","
        $singleDate = [datetime]$splitLine[0]
        $queryColumn = $splitLine[7]

        If (($queryColumn -match "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and $singleDate -ge $date1) -or ($queryColumn -notmatch "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and $singleDate -ge $date2)){
            $line
        }
    }
} | Add-Content $output
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, your code is working fine. If I leave that header in file I will get an error message because it can not compare date with header row but it will finish it OK despite that error at the beginning. Is it possible to just ignore that error and not show it? Something like -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ?

Comment: @john50 Not as clever a way to deal with it but it does work. Feel free to change the ReadCount to something bigger as you might get it to perform better.

Comment: I have one more question. As I already mention below  there is a very little difference between using -ReadCount 50 or -ReadCount 3000. To improve perforamnce, could for this kind of task be used System.IO.StreamWriter or this is not a good idea.

Comment: You could totally use the `System.IO.StreamWriter` for this. You can adopt  logic much easier using it as well. This is the approach usually taken with performance concerns. It is a good idea.

Comment: Well, based on A.D. code System.IO.StreamWriter is probably not a good idea. This is a first time when I see code using StreamWriter running slower than other method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `Import-CSV`, a `Where` statement using grouping, RegEx matching, the `-and` condition within the groupings, and the `-or` condition between them. Something like:

```
Import-CSV .\bigfile.txt | 
    where { ($_.Header8 -match "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and ([datetime]$_.Date) -ge $date1) -or ($_.Header8 -notmatch "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and ([datetime]$_.Date) -ge $date2) } | 
    Export-Csv test.txt -NoTypeInformation -append
```

**Edit:** As Matt pointed out my date comparison logic was flawed due to it considering the text from the file a string. I updated my code to fix that.

That being said, **please, for the love of God, use Matt's answer over mine!** I did not see that you have 800,000 lines in the file to be updated. My answer should work fine, but it will be agonizingly slow since it will convert the entire file to an array of objects, parse through them, and then write them all back out at once. I'm leaving the answer because it is functional, but would be better suited to smaller files.

**Edit2:** Well, if you aren't seeing any performance increase from Matt's code (you may want to alter the ReadCount to 1000 or 2000 in his code), here's updated code for mine that will strip the extra quotes out before writing it back to a file.

```
(Import-CSV C:\temp\new.txt | 
    where { ($_.Header8 -match "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and ([datetime]$_.Date) -ge $date1) -or ($_.Header8 -notmatch "(-XX|\.YY)$" -and ([datetime]$_.Date) -ge $date2) } | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"'| 
    set-content $output
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 questions to this code. Is it possible to export data to test.txt file without adding ' " ' to every record? Second question is: I've noticed that If I don't enter the date in a exact format M/d/yyyy and I enter it in format MM/dd/yyyy date filtration won't work. How can I make it more universal, so it wouldn't matter if I enter date in MM/dd/yyyy or M/d/yyyy (without leading zeros)?

Comment: Hey Mad.... would the date logic on this be flawed since it would appear to be doing string comparison and not date comparison?

Comment: Yes, After testing I can confirm, that this code is not working correctly. From my test file I've lost more than 50% of records. It is probably caused by string comparison instead of date comparison as Matt already mentioned.

Comment: Hi Mad. Probably you will be surprised but after your update running time of your code is about the same as Matt's. Only problem is that output file is significantly bigger because of those extra characters ' " '. Is Export-Csv always generating those characters? I think it must also take some time to write it. May be this code would be even faster without writing extra ' " ' characters.

Comment: I did quite a extensive testing and it looks like there is very very little difference between those numbers. It almost doesn't matter if I use -ReadCount 50 or ReadCount  3000 (time difference is 2 or 3 seconds). But there is a big time difference in running time If I use -ReadCount at all or not (over 1 minute).

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but it looked interesting. Also, this method might provide better performance. I'm using IO.StreamReader to get the file and parsing line by line and using IO.StreamWrite to output the result right away. I have not verified the conditions yet..

```
$date1 = Read-Host 'Enter date1 mm/dd/yyyy'
$date2 = Read-Host 'Enter date2 mm/dd/yyyy'
$filePath = "path\to\bigfile.txt"
$outputfile = "outfile.txt"

$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "$filePath"
$outFile = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -arg "$outputfile"

while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {

$line | % {

    $items = $_.Split(',') 
    try{ 
    [datetime]$rowDate = $items[0]
    [string]$Header8 = $items[-1]            
        If($rowDate -le $date1 -and $Header8 -match "-XX|.YY")
        {$null}
        ElseIf($rowDate-le $date2 -and $Header8 -notmatch "-XX|.YY")
        {$null}
        Else {
        $outItem = $items -join ","
        $outFile.WriteLine($outItem)}
        }    
    catch [System.Exception] {$null}
        }
    }
    $file.close()
    $outFile.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is working, but surprisingly it is significantly slower than Matt's code. (running time 4:15 vs 2:45)